# Android Javamail: Lost emails in poor reception areas

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, signal-strength

I am currently utilising the standard javamail/jsse provider setup to send emails from a predefined gmail account in an android app ie:

```
    try{
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("xxxxxxxxxxxx - No Reply" +"<xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com>"));//new InternetAddress(sender,user));
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setDataHandler(handler);
        if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
        else
            message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
        Transport.send(message);
        return true;
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("SendMail" , e.getMessage().toString());
        return false;
    }
```

The app checks connectivity before attempting to send

```
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected() && checkSignal(mContext) > 1;
```

and uses a receiver to monitor connectivity before trying again if a connection is not present.

```
    <receiver android:name=".Modules.mod_internet_receiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

For the most part the emails come through fine however I notice that some emails are lost and do not report an exception. I have identified the issue as occurring in poor and changing signal strength areas. To counteract we added some primitive signal level test and only attempt to send where a signal is greater than 1.

```
    try {
        final TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        for (final CellInfo info : tm.getAllCellInfo()) {
            if (info instanceof CellInfoGsm) {
                final CellSignalStrengthGsm gsm = ((CellInfoGsm) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                mSignalStrength = gsm.getLevel();
                Log.d("GSM Signal",String.valueOf(mSignalStrength));
                break;
            } else if (info instanceof CellInfoCdma) {
                final CellSignalStrengthCdma cdma = ((CellInfoCdma) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                mSignalStrength = cdma.getLevel();
                Log.d("CDMA Signal",String.valueOf(mSignalStrength));
                break;
            } else if (info instanceof CellInfoLte) {
                final CellSignalStrengthLte lte = ((CellInfoLte) info).getCellSignalStrength();
                mSignalStrength = lte.getLevel();
                Log.d("LTE Signal",String.valueOf(mSignalStrength));
                break;
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Unknown type of cell signal!");
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Telephony", "Unable to obtain cell signal information", e);
        mSignalStrength = 0;
    }
    Log.d("Signal Strength",String.valueOf(mSignalStrength));
    return mSignalStrength;
```

This is working fine but I realise that this signal can vary at any point so whilst the email is sent immediately after the check there is the possibility that the signal can still drop during sending thereby resulting in lost emails. I was thinking I could add a second check a couple of seconds later to see if the signal was stable but these are all just workarounds that don't ensure success.

I have looked into the Javamail FAQ as here https://stackoverflow.com/a/30634257/9175763 but this is not a delivery failure rather a connection issue.

I am wondering if anyone has any suggestions on a better way to counteract this issue?

Comment: If Transport.send returns without throwing an Exception, the message should be safely on your server and not lost.  What are you doing in your app when Transport.send fails?  You can retry a few times, but then what?  Perhaps you can save the message locally and try again when the signal strength improves.

Comment: Emails are stored in a queue. When Transport.send runs successfully the email is removed from the queue. When an exception is thrown a broadcast receiver is triggered and re-trys after a connectivity change (ie connection made).  Unfortunately Transport.send in rare instances does not report an exception and the email is not found on the server (GMail sent items in this case). A basic signal level test was added but this doesn't ensure an outcome given the signal can drop at any time.  I therefore considered this a poor workaround and was hoping there was some option I had missed.Thanks

Comment: If the server accepts the message and reports success to JavaMail, allowing Transport.send to return successfully, but the server doesn't really have the message, there's a serious bug in the server.  On the other hand, if some connection failure causes Transport.send to return success even though the server never replied, that's a bug in JavaMail.  The [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) can help determine which case applies.

Comment: Thanks Bill, technically then unless there is a bug either in my code or Gmail servers/Javamail the result I am seeing is not possible. I would guess then that the issue is probably at my end and/or I'm not taking into account correctly the actions of the end users. I haven't been able to replicate the issue when connected to the console so I'll add debug output to a text log and try to isolate this further. Appreciate the response.